# Using Accelerometer and Gyroscope to Get a Phone's Approximate Position in Space

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, motion-detection

I am familiar with traditional motion and object tracking techniques, however, I am wondering if there is a way I can track a modern phone in 3D space without imaging. By modern I mean it has a touch screen, a gyroscope, and an accelerometer. Is there a way to use the gyroscope and accelerometer to track the phone in 3D space fairly accurately (within an inch for every foot of movement) or am I misunderstanding these technologies? Thanks!

Comment: I have flagged this as too broad since you aren't really asking a specific programming question. This is more of a question of "Is X possible?", which is too broad to be answered well here. The possible responses you would get are either "Yes it is possible", "No it is impossible", (both of which are too short to be useful on Stack Overflow) or "Yes, and here is a dissertation on how to do it", which would be far too long for an SO answer

Answer (score 1):

The process of maintaining estimates of your position via gyroscopic and accelerometer data is called "dead reckoning".  Google will tell you all about it now that you know the magic words.

It can be pretty good for short periods, but the error accumulates over time. So you can't maintain accuracy of 1 inch or even a foot for very long.

Smartphone hardware is probably good enough to, say, take over for GPS when you drive through a tunnel.

You can also also use dead reckoning combined with GPS to give you more accurate and responsive position updates than you can get with either one alone.

Comment: I have heard of this term before. Because of the accumulated error, do you think I could supplement this with some sort of motion tracking / object following to maintain its approximate position in 2D space, then use that to calculate a) how large the error is (at least in 2D space, which could be extended to 3D space) b) help to track it in 3D space?

Comment: I don't know what your application is, but yes that sort of thing is possible in many cases.